# Intellij Idea gives wrong error: gradle.build is not part of project

Tags: eclipse, gradle, intellij-idea

I imported Gradle Spring Boot 2.0 project from Eclipse to Intellij Idea 18.1 using import eclipse model. But when I tried to edit build.gradle file in the project in Intellij Idea I got the error: build.gradle is not part of the project...

What did I do wrong to cause this error in order to fix it?

Comment: gradle.build ? Is it a real file ?

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't import this project into intelliJ directly as gradle project w/o the eclipse indirection. Maybe you might need to add the intellij gradle plugin to your build.

Comment: dpr, When I imported eclipse gradle project, IDEA gave me the default as eclipse model. I am not sure what is the best way to import existing project.